# Optimal pairs of farthest points

Tags: graph-algorithm, linear-programming, hungarian-algorithm

I have a even set of points in 2D. I need an algorithm that can make pairs of those points such that total sum of distance between pairs is maximum.

Dynamic Programming, greedy approach won't work, I think.
Can I use Linear Programming or Hungarian algo? or any other?

Comment: Could you explain how you would apply the Hungarian method? I don't see it. Just out of curiosity: what is it you are trying to solve?

Comment: The problem can be formulated as an integer linear program for sure but it's performance will be `O(exp(N))`.

Comment: @OP, Unless you have a compelling reason for a polynomial algorithm, the IP should work fine. Do you need to solve this extremely quickly many times? Could you use a heuristic?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can use integer linear programming. Here is an example formulation:

Introduce a binary variable `x[ij]` for each unordered couple of distrinct points `i` and `j` (i.e. such as `i<j`), where `x[ij]=1` iff the points `i` and `j` are grouped together.

Compute all the distances `d[ij]` (for `i<j`).

The objective is to maximize `sum_[i<j] d[ij]*x[ij]`, subject to the constraints that each point is in exactly one pair, i.e. `forall j, sum_[i<j] x[ij] = 1`.

Note that this work also for 3d points: you only need the distance between two pairs of points.

Comment: Thank you Sir, 
But with linear programming Algorithm complexity is at least O(n*n). As this an assignment problem,, lil modification in Hungarian algorithm can solve problem in O(N).

Comment: I disagree with your complexity analysis, integer linear programming is certainly not polynomial. I don't think that you could use Hungarian algorithm for this, your graph is not bipartite. It look like a (weighted) maximal perfect matching algorithm, see Edmond's algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27s_matching_algorithm (in particular the reference 10 seems to be exactly what you want).